# How to populate buttons of custom keyboard from the list and make this keyboard work?

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create a custom keyboard for telegram bot using google apps scripts.

I also want to fill my keyboard with values from this method:

```
function keyboardValues() {
  var keyboardValues = sheet.getRange("B11:G81").getValues();
  var names = [];
  var array = keyboardValues.map(function(keyboardValue) {
    names.push(keyboardValue[0]);
  })
  names = JSON.stringify(names);
  return names;
}
```

This is my POST method:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = contents.message.text;
  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  var keyboard = keyboardValues();
  if (text == "/start"){
    var message = "Choose the name: ";
    var keyboard = JSON.stringify({
    keyboard: [[{text: 'OK'},{text: 'OK'}]],
    one_time_keyboard: true, 
    resize_keyboard: true
    });
    sendText(id, message, keyboard);
  }
}

function sendText (id, text, reply_markup ){
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text + "&reply_markup=" + reply_markup ;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

Please help me to populate keyboard button values with values from result of keyboardValues() method and how to make a custom keyboard working, because now it doesn't work.

Comment: `doPost()` runs when a POST request is made to the published URL of the Web App.  Sorry if you already know that, but I just wanted to make sure.  What is the response coming back from the GET request being made by `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`  You can view the value in the variable `response` by using a `Logger.log('response: ' + response)` statement, running the code, and then choose the View menu and Logs.

Comment: Thanks, but I know the value of response, but I don't know how to populate the button values and also how to make my custom kyboard work, because it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is wrong? What is HTTP response from telegram server? Is mesaage being actually sent without a keyboard, or request fails with an error?

Comment: Ok. I have a Google SpreadSheet with some data (about mosaic at warehouse). I want to write a name of mosaic to my telegram bot, and then I want it to send me information about the remaining amount of mosaic in the warehouse from the cell of Google SpreadSheet. 

To avoid mistakes when entering the name of the mosaic (I do not remember them all), I would like to drive the names of all the mosaics into the keys of the pop-up keyboard of the telegraph. This is my problem, @IvanVinogradov. Do you know how to help me wit it?

Comment: Hm, your code looks okay to me, though I dont't know JS well. Just a thought - try to achieve desirable result with a) plain HTTP requests via `curl` - maybe URL encoding is incorrect? and b) use `InlineKeyboard` instead of `ReplyKeyboard`. And i suggest you to use POST instead of GET for such requests because a) it is  easier to write and debug and b) according to RFC GET should be used only to retrieve information from the server.

Comment: So, with your current code, is message being actually sent (but without a keyboard), or request fails and nothing is sent at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving the same task. I get all not empty items from one column and make keyboard buttons from it. May be my decision will be useful for anyone. I use code mostly from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431352/telegram-bot-keyboard-with-google-apps-script/72147367#72147367) and change it for buttons from Google Sheets.

Keyboard function:

```
function sendKeyboard(chatId, choices, text) {
  const buttons = transformArrayToKeyboard(choices);
  const replyKeyboardMarkup = {keyboard: buttons, 
                one_time_keyboard: true,
                resize_keyboard: true};
  const replyMarkup = JSON.stringify(replyKeyboardMarkup);
  const url = telegramApi + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + encodeURIComponent(chatId) + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text) + '&disable_web_page_preview=true&reply_markup=' + encodeURIComponent
  (replyMarkup);
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Function to transform items to keyboard with 3 buttons in row:

```
function transformArrayToKeyboard(choices) {
  const maxLengthRowKeyboardMenu = 3;
  const arr = choices.map(item => ({text: item }));
  const result = [];
  let index = 0;
  while(arr.slice(index).length > 0) {
    const newRowValuesForButtons = arr.slice(index,index+maxLengthRowKeyboardMenu);
    result.push(newRowValuesForButtons);
    index += maxLengthRowKeyboardMenu;
  }
  return result;
}
```

May be the most important: Telegram keyboard needs to be array of array. So:

```
function flatten(arrayOfArrays) {
  return [].concat.apply([],arrayOfArrays);
}
```

To sent keyboard:

```
  const bazaDan = ss.getSheetByName('Your_sheetname');
  const choices = flatten(bazaDan.getRange("D5:D").getValues().filter(String));
  const text = 'Your_text';
  sendKeyboard(id, choices, text);
```